# Error when compiling official Angular2 meteor tutorial

Tags: angular, meteor, cmd

Iam doing right now my first angular 2 meteor tutroial here is the link:

https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding

in the capitel 4.3 bind Mongo observable....

my code is looking like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

parties: Observable<any[]>;

constructor() {      
this.parties = Parties.find({}).zone();

  {'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone'
    'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.'
    'location': 'Palo Alto'
  },
  {'name': 'All dubstep all the time'
    'description': 'Get it on!'
    'location': 'Palo Alto'
  },
  {'name': 'Savage lounging'
    'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.'
    'location': 'San Francisco'
  },
  };
  }
```

now i go to the console to start the localhost an i get this error:

```
 While building for web.browser:
 client/imports/app/app.component.ts:16:11: ';' expected.

 Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

in the lines between 11 and 16 is in my code :

```
export class AppComponent {

parties: Observable<any[]>;

constructor() {      
this.parties = Parties.find({}).zone();

  {'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone'
    'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.'
```

and somewhere in this lines a comma is expected but i dont know where.
Thank you for every help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the start of the object. I added the line

```
var something = {
```

The tutorial probably wants something else.

You also need commas at the end of every line when constructing a list, and no comma at the end (although ES6 tolerates this). This is what your code should look like.

```
export class AppComponent {

parties: Observable<any[]>;

constructor() {      
this.parties = Parties.find({}).zone();

var something = {  
  {'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone',
    'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.',
    'location': 'Palo Alto'
  },
  {'name': 'All dubstep all the time',
    'description': 'Get it on!',
    'location': 'Palo Alto'
  },
  {'name': 'Savage lounging',
    'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.',
    'location': 'San Francisco'
  }
};
```